# Mapping a Piped Shell Command in Vim

Tags: mac, shell, vim

In a previous question I asked about outputting evaluated code to a new window in MacVim. I got a great solution, but it presented another question: How can I map a key command in my `.vimrc` that involves piping output in the shell?

As a simple example, let's say I wanted to pipe the results of `ls -a` to a new MacVim window. From the Vim command line I can enter `!ls -a | mvim -`, and the results will appear in a new window. Great! Now, I add that to my `.vimrc`:

```
 nmap <Leader>r :w !ls | mvim -<CR>
```

Vim now throws an error every time I try to source my `.vimrc`, which reads as follows:

```
E492: Not an editor command:  mvim -<CR>
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try putting this in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
nmap <Leader>r :w !ls <bar> mvim -<CR>
```

or

```
nmap <Leader>r :w !ls \| mvim -<CR>
```

Comment: awesome. i had tried escaping with `\|` to no avail. i didn't know you could use <bar>. thanks!

Comment: I've been using vim for almost a decade.  Ran into this today.  Found an answer almost 10 years old.  Amazing.  Thanks from the future!